# mapKit: performing a segue after user selects an annotation marker

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, segue

I'm having trouble **performing a segue** from a mapKit annotation to an other view controller on another storyboard.

I have a storyboard with a full screen map view and i want to perform a segue to the other storyboard containing the PanelViewController.

[image]
[image]

After adding a MKAnnotation to the map using `map.addAnnotation()`, i use `mapView(_:didSelect:)` to get the currently selected marker. I know i have to perform the segue here but i don't know how.

I guess i have **2 options**, but none of them work:

> present(PanelViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

This gives me an error: "`Cannot convert value of type 'PanelViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'`"

> performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPanel", sender: view)

This crashes the app with an uncaught exception error:  "`Receiver (<myApp.MapViewController: 0x109200f80>) has no segue with identifier 'showPanel`"

Ofcourse this is true since i don't have a segue with this identifier on this view controller. I don't know how i would create one since it's just a full screen mapKit view and xcode doesn't allow me to ctr+drag from the mapKit view to the other view controler.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 present(PanelViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

should be instance , create storyborad id named **nextID** for the VC `PanelViewController` in IB

```
  let stoBr = UIStoryboard(name: "nameOfSB", bundle: nil)
  let next = stoBr.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextID") as! PanelViewController

 // here configuew next properties

  present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

and this

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPanel", sender: view)
```

The current VC you do segue from must have segue named **showPanel** to destination VC

[image]

Comment: hi, thx... when i use an instance i get a black screen and not the existing view. My current VC indeed doesn't have a segue named showPanel, how do i add it when there is only a full screen map view?

Comment: thx for your update, but i think i'm not clear, i have added some screenshots to my original question. So i don't need to create a storyboard since i already have one.

Comment: I didn't say create storyboard the line above gets a VC inside it with it's id

Comment: Ok, that sort of works but i'm using multiple storyboards, so your code gives me this error: Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x1c4074880>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PanelViewController'

Comment: first you should access the VC in it's storyboard and give it storyboard ID **PanelViewController** as the attached photo in answer , see edit

Comment: If i would go the performSegue() route... how should i do that?